# Retina Macbook Pro 13" makes clicking noise once a second

Tags: macbook-pro

It's hard to describe the noise, so here's a recording. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDh-2qxeUGw&feature=youtu.be

My half-year-old retina MBP 13" started to make this clicking noise about once a second. The sound is very consistent, and just never stops. What is this, have you had it and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only moveable part in a retina macbook pro 13" is the fan as seen on the following picture: (courtesy of ifixit)

[image: MacbookPro13]

Therefore it must be an issue with the fan, particularly because the noise originates from the right side (imagine the macbook pro flipped and the fan will be on the right side). Either the fan failed or something got stuck in the fan and is preventing it from spinning. I suggest you take it into an Apple Store so they can have a look at it in detail.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is a great relief! Apple store opens in a few hours here, I'll head over there and inquire.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem, please let me know what they have to say. Since I'm not able to recreate the problem in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't live near an Apple store, you can use a stethoscope or a piece of tubing to localize the noise. Check around the speakers, the keyboard, the trackpad and also on the back of the display and the back of the unibody enclosure.

Quite rapidly, you will know exactly where the noise is and you can usually tell what's causing the noise from ifixit repair guides or a follow-on question here with your specific model and your specific location of noise.